# Override component toString method in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

How to override the toString method of a class component in reactjs?

Here is the code

```
class C1 extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {C2.toString()}
      </div>
    )

  }
}

class C2 extends React.Component{
  toString(){
    return "c2";
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <C1 />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

https://codepen.io/cheng-mo/pen/Odvbjw?&editable=true&editors=0010

expected to show "c2" on the page instead of the whole object string

Answer (score 1):

A class component must implement render() method because it’s mandatory. In your code C2 component will not work because it doesn’t implement render method. So change C2 class component to functional component

```
    export function C2{
        return "c2";
    }
```

And change your C1 component to something like below

```
   class C1 extends React.Component{
     render(){
        return (
         <div>
            <C2 />
        </div>
        ) }
   }
```

If you to continue with class component for C2 then

Change

```
   class C2 extends React.Component{
        toString(){
            return "c2";
        }
   }
```

To

```
 class C2 extends React.Component{
         render(){
              return "c2"
         }
   }
```

And C1 component should look like below

```
  class C1 extends React.Component{
     render(){
        return (
         <div>
            <C2 />
        </div>
        ) }
   }
```

Comment: what if my class C2 has a render method.